# VB Renaming Files with 2 textbox inputs

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use 2 textboxes in a form to Rename Files, but keep getting "Expression Expected".  The first & & is the name of a server and the second & & is the original name of the file.  The reason I need them to be textboxes is because those names constantly change.

`My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("D:\File1\" & S2Prim.Text & "_Working\Backup\" & PSG.Text &, "group.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `&` character at the end of the first parameter:

```
"D:\File1\" & S2Prim.Text & "_Working\Backup\" & PSG.Text &
```